# Image Conversion and Resizing Function Outputting Blank Image

Tags: php, gd

Building a ConvertImage() function that was taken from portions of code I've written over the years that my sites already use, it should convert (if BMP or GIF) and resize an image that is being supplied to it as a data string. It's working and the images are being returned in the proper size but as blanks. Apparently I missed something important but what?

Note that this is not uploading the image anywhere and it is not inserting it into a database column, at least not at this time. Its purpose is simply to resize and convert it and unfortunately ImageMagick is not yet available.

For testing, a simple form submits the image from the file system to this, which also calls the functions (see the remarks in the function for details about the parameters):

```
<?php include_once("/var/www/html/site.loc/functions.php");
    if (isset($_FILES['fileToProcess'])) :

        $file = $_FILES['fileToProcess'];
        $image = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);

        $image = ConvertImage($image, 250, "Width");

        ShowImage($image);
    endif;
?>
```

Then here are the functions:

```
// Converts images to jpg (or to png if gif) and resizes them
// $MaxDim is a value for final width or height of the image. Use $SizeCentric to specify.
function ConvertImage($ImgFile, $MaxDim, $SizeCentric) {

    global $Message;

    list($ImgWidth, $ImgHeight, $ImgType, $Attr) = getimagesizefromstring($ImgFile);

    if ($ImgType) :
        switch ($ImgType) :
            case 1 : $src = imagecreatefromgif($ImgFile);  break;
            case 2 : $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($ImgFile); break;
            case 3 : $src = imagecreatefrompng($ImgFile);  break;
            case 6 : $src = imagecreatefrombmp($ImgFile); break;
            default : $Message .= "Unsupported image type. You may upload only JPG, GIF, PNG or BMP images.\n\n";
        endswitch;

        if ($src === FALSE) $Message = "Unable to create image.";

        // Calculate new dimensions from $MaxDim based on whether $SizeCentric is the Width or the Height
        // However, do not stretch the image beyond its current size
        if (strtolower($SizeCentric) === "height") :
            if ($ImgHeight > $MaxDim) :
                $newHeight = $MaxDim;
                $newWidth = round( $ImgWidth * ($newHeight/$ImgHeight));
            else :
                $newHeight = $ImgHeight;
                $newWidth = $ImgWidth;
            endif;
        else :
            if ($ImgWidth > $MaxDim) :
                $newWidth = $MaxDim;
                $newHeight = round($ImgHeight * ($newWidth / $ImgWidth));
            else :
                $newHeight = $ImgHeight;
                $newWidth = $ImgWidth;
            endif;
        endif;

        $processimg = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

        // Maintain any GIF or PNG transparencies
        if ($ImgType == 1 || $ImgType == 3) :
            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($processimg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
            imagefill($processimg, 0, 0, $transparent);
            imagealphablending($processimg, FALSE);
            imagesavealpha($processimg, TRUE);
        endif;

        imagecopyresampled($processimg, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0,$newWidth, $newHeight, $ImgWidth, $ImgHeight);

        // Convert image to JPG or PNG
        ob_start();
            switch ($ImgType) :
                case 1 : 
                case 3 : imagepng($processimg, null); break;
                default : imagejpeg($processimg, null, 100);
            endswitch;
            $image = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean(); 

        imagedestroy($processimg);
    endif;

    if (!empty($Message)) :
        $_SESSION['Message'] = $Message;
    endif;

    //(isset($image) && strlen($image) > 0) return $image;
    return $image;
}
```

This very basic ShowImage() function is used for testing the function above and others not yet created by displaying the image stream to the screen:

```
// Used for diagnosing and testing image processing functions
function ShowImage($image) {

    $mimetype = getimagesizefromstring($image);

    // Add headers and output the image
    Header("Pragma: no-cache");
    Header('Content-type: ' . $mimetype['mime']);

    echo $image;
}
```

Comment: So `$image` is the result of capturing the output buffer (ie binary data as a a string) yet you then try and use that in `exif_imagetype()` which accepts a filename argument. See the problem?

Comment: @Phil I've rewritten the `ShowImage()` function to eliminate `exif_imagetype()` per your suggestion to a more run of the mill way of getting the mime type even though `exif_imagetype()` was doing so but no better results than before. I must have missed something in ConvertImage() so any other thoughts?

Comment: One inconsistency at least is: `getimagesizefromstring($ImgFile)` here, you treat `$ImgFile` as image data (because that's what `getimagesizefromstring` expects). Then later, you use that same `$ImgFile` with any of the `imagecreatefrom*` functions. But those expect file paths. You might want to start with switching to `getimagesize`.

Comment: Thank you for that. $ImgFile is indeed image data rather than a path and `getimagesize()` won't work with data. Unless there are other similar functions that will work with image data, maybe I'm going about this wrong and should be using the "uploaded" file's temp file, then convert the output to image data once the resizing and conversions are done. ***NOTE:*** *it appears that an edit to my question has somehow deleted the code used to call the image in the first place so I'll put that back in momentarily.*

Answer (score 0):

Taking a chance here by answering my own question but based on the comments by @Phil and @Yoshi I realized that I was mixing apples and oranges. Rather than trying to do the processing on the image data as some if it was using, the bulk of the functions being called required a file path. Since I'm not actually creating a physical file at this time, I simply used the temp file and made only one change to the `ConvertImage()` function per @Yoshi (changed `getimagesizefromstring()` to `getimagesize()`), then made the rest of the modifications to the code that is processing the form submission to the function. @Phil's changes were already made to the original question.

```
<?php include_once("/var/www/html/site.loc/functions.php");

if (isset($_FILES['fileToProcess'])) :
    $image = $_FILES['fileToProcess']['tmp_name'];
    $image = ConvertImage($image, 250, "Width", "");
    ShowImage($image);
endif;
?>
```

Comment: There are lots of great, production ready image processing libraries out there on Packagist. Why not give em a try?

Comment: Good question! It's because I am trying, for now, to maintain compatibility with some legacy code on about a dozen sites and, while I can install libraries on my own development systems, I cannot do so on the hosted live server.